# Squid isn't spawning in my farm (plz help)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a 15*15 farm. Its 64 to 46. full of water. It took so much time to do it. Your help will be appreciated. [Here is my picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dhSP.jpg)
[image: and full view]

Comment: NOW it is a proper duplicate, because I've edited the answer to also include information about the biome. This farm was built in the wrong biome.

Comment: If you don't mind changing to Creative, you could always put a spawner down there. It is kinda cheaty though. :\

Comment: I see biome: minecraft:plains - if the volume is not in the river or ocean biome, it won't spawn squid.

Answer (score 0):

The water may be too small. You may want to get a bucket, and scoop up a squid (if possible). Then empty the squid into your pool. You can find squids in an ocean biome.

Answer (score -1):

Try to go afk next to your farm covered by dirt. Mobs will only spawn in the chunk you're in.